# "Map Division" Without a UDF in Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We are using a User Defined Function (UDF) to perform "Map Division" on two MapType columns in a dataset. What "Map Division" means is creating a new map with keys that are in common between the dividend and the divisor, and values that are the value of the dividend divided by the value of the divisor for that key. The Scala code to create the UDF is shown below.

```
def mapDivision(dividend: Map[String, Double], divisor: Map[String, Long]): Map[String, Double] = {
  var result = Map.empty[String, Double]
  for ((key, value) <- dividend) if (divisor.contains(key)) result += (key -> value / divisor(key))
  result
}
```

We would like to perform this operation without the use of this UDF, because UDFs cannot be optimized by the Catalyst Engine and are slow. We have tried to perform this operation using only the Spark SQL API in order to attain a performance boost over the UDF, but have been unable to come up with a good way to do so that works and isn't actually slower due to roundabout joins etc.

Does anybody know of a fast and simple way to perform this operation using the Spark SQL API?

Comment: How are you obtaining these maps? Are they the result of joining other Datasets?

Comment: The Maps in question being divided are a result of aggregations and transformations on an input dataset. I did just have the idea that I may be able to form the result map from the input dataset at the same time as the others rather than trying to divide the two finished map columns, I am going to attempt that now.

Comment: I was able to obtain the map I wanted by making it at the same time as the other maps with calculations on the raw data, but I am still curious how this operation can be quickly performed if that were not an option.

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion. I imagine doing this in sql would be quite verbose.